# NSInvalidArgumentException while running Adobe Air app with native extension on ios

Tags: ios, air, ios-simulator, air-native-extension, ane

I have compiled ANE plugin with external Obj-C dependencies:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/18.0">
    <description>iPhone platform description</description>
    <sdkVersion>8.4</sdkVersion>
    <linkerOptions>
        <option>-ios_version_min 7.0</option>
        <option>-framework Foundation</option>
        <option>-weak_framework AdSupport</option>
        <option>-framework AVFoundation</option>
        <option>-framework AudioToolbox</option>
        <!--option>-framework CoreTelefony</option-->
        <option>-framework CoreGraphics</option>
        <option>-framework EventKit</option>
        <option>-framework EventKitUI</option>
        <option>-framework MessageUI</option>
        <option>-weak_framework StoreKit</option>
        <option>-framework SystemConfiguration</option>
        <option>-framework CoreLocation</option>
        <option>-framework UIKit</option>
        <option>-framework Social</option>
        <option>-framework WebKit</option>
        <option>-framework CoreMedia</option>
        <option>-framework MediaPlayer</option>
        <option>-framework QuartzCore</option>
        <option>-framework CoreImage</option>
        <option>-framework CoreFoundation</option>
        <option>-framework CFNetwork</option>
        <option>-lc++</option>
        <option>-lz</option>
        <option>-lsqlite3</option>
        <option>-lxml2.2</option>
    </linkerOptions>
    <packagedDependencies>
        <packagedDependency>MyStatic.framework</packagedDependency>
    </packagedDependencies>
</platform>
```

ANE plugin compiles without any exception. When i trying to run sample AIR app on iOS simulator i get this:

```
$> adt -installApp -platform ios -platformsdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -device ios-simulator -package out/production/sample/Sample.ipa

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: MCMMetadataIdentifier)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c9f703c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8c44776e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c8ddc66 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 1174
3   isb                                 0x00000001021f8433 -[iPhoneSimulator createMetaDataPList:withID:] + 314
4   isb                                 0x00000001021f8bff -[iPhoneSimulator installApp:sdkRoot:] + 742
5   isb                                 0x00000001021f9b40 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 1275
6   isb                                 0x00000001021f9e35 main + 101
7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff941485c9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
/var/folders/7y/7xytqjbx5wggzc246fwrv1zm0000gq/T/cmd6670868742567092003.tmp: line 1: 19356 Abort trap: 6
        "/Users/ewgenius/Documents/flex_sdk_4.6/lib/aot/bin/isb/isb" "-install" "-apppath" "/var/folders/7y/7xytqjbx5wggzc246fwrv1zm0000gq/T/7239e3f7-d560-4f18-8d66-674f841b4a0f/Payload/Sample.app" "-sdkpath" "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk"
```

But when i compile ANE plugin without MyStatic.framework and it's dependencies, sample app is running well. Any ideas?

Comment: You should show the code that is causing the exception? `setObjectForKey`

Comment: @Michael, i can't provide code causing exception, because this error appears when i'm trying to run app on ios simulator. It is code from ios sdk(or air sdk, what usses ios sdk methods), as you can see from above logs, exception throws from:
[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]
[iPhoneSimulator createMetaDataPList:withID:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Packaged dependency **MyStatic.framework** have Resources folder, and i copied the entire folder to `ios` directory for build command `adt package -target ane -platform iPhone-ARM -C ios/ . -platformoptions ../build/platformios.xml`. When i move all files from `ios/Resources` to `ios/` i was able to run my app without exception.